# "Invalid data found when processing input" no matter the FFMPEG configuration

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg

I've been stumped on this for a while now, no matter the configuration if use in NodeJS I always get the same error "Error: ffmpeg exited with code 1".

Here's my code:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {

    var seektime = 100;
    var pathToMovie = __dirname + '/src/video.mp4';
    var stat = fs.statSync(pathToMovie);
    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'video/mp4',
        'Content-Length': stat.size
    });

    var proc = new ffmpeg(pathToMovie)
    .seekInput(seektime)
    .withVideoBitrate(1024)
    .withVideoCodec('libx264')
    .withAspect('16:9')
    .withFps(24)
    .toFormat('mp4');

    var ffstream = proc.pipe(res, {end:true});
    ffstream.on('data', function(chunk) {
        console.log('ffmpeg just wrote ' + chunk.length + ' bytes');
    });

});
server.listen(8000);
```

I have no idea what to do now. Any ideas?

Thanks,
Jamie